# Google Apps will not accept deleted domain as alias, claims in use

Tags: google-workspace

I had two domains registered under separate Google Apps accounts. I decided that I would like to add domain (B) to domain (A) as an alias instead of having two separate Google Apps instances.

I was instructed that I would need to delete domain (B) from the Google Apps service. After deleting (which may take up to five (5) days), I figured I should be able to add the domain as an alias to my main Google Apps domain (A).

However, I keep receiving a message stating:

> This domain name has already been used as an alias or domain.

I understand that it may take a bit for Google to realize that I have indeed removed my domain from their apps, thus freeing it to attach as an alias, but how long does it take?

Is there anything I can try to resolve this issue? It has been over a week and I am worried I will never be able to use my domain as an alias.

Comment: How long ago did you remove domain B from Google Apps? I have been through this process before, and it did indeed take 5 full days before I was able to claim it again.

(I did not notice this was asked 5 months ago...)

Answer (score 2):

**You need to contact Google Apps support.** They can force update your account.

This happened to me (along with one other issue) when I was setting up a Google Apps account. I sent them an email and to my surprise I got a phone call from an engineer within a few hours who sorted the problem out.

**The Google Apps admin support page is here:
http://support.google.com/a/bin/request.py**

You will need your Customer PIN & Support PIN.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried called Google Apps ?
I was going to go through this process for our two accounts sometime this month.

But I believe they will be your best point of contact, as in Google Apps you can't force updates (not to my knowledge), sorry I can't help further.